# QGIS Variable Symbol Levels / Layer Rendering

Tags: qgis

I am trying to display a regular series of circles that are sized and colored differently based on their attributes. So for example:

[image]

Let's say attribute A is green, B is blue, C is yellow.

I always want the smallest circle on top, then the next smallest, etc. So object one the display order (top to bottom) would be Attributes A B C, but in Object 2 the order would have to be Attributes B C A.

I hope this is clear. I can't figure out how to do this. I can separate the information to layers but can only have a static rendering order.

I could control the symbols levels but again, this is static.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik gave a good solution and that was legitimate if I was in fact using a small number of attributes, like 2 or 3, even 4. In order to accommodate all possible variations of A > B > C, or A > C > B, there would be 3!, 4!, etc. possible combinations and therefore rules.

This is extraordinarily tedious and one mistake would be terrible to track down and fix.

A workaround for someone trying to recreate this methodology could be to first convert the points to polygons by buffering them. A nice feature is that a variable distance buffer using the sizing 'Assistant' allows you to use an exponential scale based on an attribute.

These buffers could all be combined into the same layer and their area measured with the field calculator. At the bottom of the properties --> symbology tab are the layer rendering features, and you can check the box for control feature rendering order, then have the various polygons rendered by their area.

Effectively this would do the same thing as I wanted to do initially. Not as easy as I was hoping, however because points have no area the layer ordering option wouldn't work and the rule-based solution was seemingly the only one, but as I said if there were 5 or more attributes this would be overly complex and too easy to make a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

From a cartographic POV your idea is at least troublesome. This could lead to too much information present in the map, and also to collissions if you have identical values for two attributes.

Option 1: Use diagrams in addition to points.

Option 2: Add the values as textlabels.

Option 3: Work with patterns/transparency instead of shuffling the symbol-order all the time.

Option 4: If it has to be your way, you can solve this by using rule-based styling. For each possible combination of the three values create a rule like `"A">="B">="C"`, then have each marker consist of three separate markers, which you must order so the smallest values comes out on top (in this example-rule `C`). There still is the problem of identical values.

Comment: That's fantastic! Well done Erik. Options 1-3 would be suitable for a different end goal, as this is data visualization more than cartography. However your approach using rule-based styling seems to do the trick. Something brand new for me in QGIS but I have done a small test and it seems to be working. Thanks very much! Hopefully this can help others in the future too.